# Console-based Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've used Rails to build web apps, but I'm wondering whether it's possible to build an app that is purely console-based, where I can connect to it via command-line and interact with it?

For example, suppose I have the following program

```
p "Please enter a command: "
userInput = gets.strip
while userInput != "quit"
  p "You entered %s!" %userInput
  p "Please enter a command: " 
  userInput = gets.strip
end
p "Bye!"
```

1. How would I write such an application using Rails?
2. How would I connect to it? With a browser-based application, I could use a web browser, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite common to have such scripts. You simply put them in the script folder and start them with:

```
rails runner script/my_script.rb
```

You would then connect to the server with ssh and just run them that way.

Comment: That is a lot simpler than what I had imagined. I will try and see what I can do!

Comment: Hmm what if I wanted to allow others to connect to it as well? Would they have to ssh to my server as well or is there a way to expose a REST API or a "public entrance" of some sort.